# how can i get query response of prolog in c#

Tags: c#, ffi, swi-prolog

I am using swi prolog with c# as front end. If i put a query like:

```
Plquery.Plcall("assert(father(sam,lia))");
```

I want to to display whether the the query is executed or not in a mmessagebox. So i need the answer in 'true' or 'false' like it comes in prolog console.

Comment: have you checked any of the documentation for the `swi prolog` to see if there are any examples..? also what you are showing in regards to the 1 line of code, where are you executing and or calling any method or routine to display the messagebox.. please provide more code to support your question

Comment: possible duplicate of [true - false response of query from prolog in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634054/true-false-response-of-query-from-prolog-in-c-sharp)